# Parse JSON into dictionary object in SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, web-services, swift, dictionary

I posted this question earlier 
[Swift: Parsing Json string and populating information into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335280/swift-parsing-json-string-and-populating-information-into-a-dictionary)

but I have a slightly different issue now. So I am posting this modified question again. I am a new developer and trying to learn SWIFT.

I call the web service http://www.kuakes.com/json/ in my swift program as follows

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let httpMethod = "GET"

    /* We have a 15-second timeout for our connection */
    let timeout = 15

    var urlAsString = "http://www.kuakes.com/json/"


    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)

    /* Set the timeout on our request here */
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url,
        cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 15.0)

    urlRequest.HTTPMethod = httpMethod

    let queue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest,
        queue: queue,
        completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,
            data: NSData!,
            error: NSError!) in

            if data.length > 0 && error == nil{
                let html = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("html = \(html)")
            } else if data.length == 0 && error == nil{
                println("Nothing was downloaded")
            } else if error != nil{
                println("Error happened = \(error)")
            }

        }
```

and get the following result

> [{"response":1,"message":"OK","count":50},{"id":145608,"title":"M 0.9
>   Explosion - 19km E of Morton,
>   Washington","link":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/uw60985917","source":"http://www.kuakes.com","north":46.536999,"west":122.021004,"lat":46.536499,"lng":-122.021164,"depth":0,"mag":0.9,"time":"2015-04-10
>   21:26:07 UTC","timestamp":1428701167},{"id":145609,"title":"M 2.3 -
>   27km W of Anchor Point,
>   Alaska","link":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak11550832","source":"http://www.kuakes.com","north":59.820999,"west":152.307999,"lat":59.820702,"lng":-152.308197,"depth":59,"mag":2.3,"time":"2015-04-10
>   20:30:09 UTC","timestamp":1428697809},{"id":145610,"title":"M 2.2 -
>   23km ENE of Red Bluff,
>   California","link":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72429666","source":"http://www.kuakes.com","north":40.293999,"west":122.000999,"lat":40.294167,"lng":-122.001335,"depth":10,"mag":2.2,"time":"2015-04-10
>   20:19:01 UTC","timestamp":1428697141},{"id":145611,"title":"M 2.8 -
>   54km N of Dorado, Puerto
>   Rico","link":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/pr15100004","source":"http://www.kuakes.com","north":18.951,"west":66.219002,"lat":18.951401,"lng":-66.219101,"depth":28,"mag":2.8,"time":"2015-04-10
>   20:05:46 UTC","timestamp":1428696346},

I would like to parse the above json result into ONE dictionary object such as the key will be id and the value will be the rest of the corresponding string. So the first entry of the dictionary object will be as follows:

> id = 145609"
>
> title:"M 2.3 - 27km W of Anchor Point,
>   Alaska","link":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ak11550832","source":"http://www.kuakes.com","north":59.820999,"west":152.307999,"lat":59.820702,"lng":-152.308197,"depth":59,"mag":2.3,"time":"2015-04-10
>   20:30:09 UTC","timestamp":1428697809}

second entry in the dictionary would like this

> id = 145609
>
> "title":"M 2.2 - 23km ENE of Red Bluff,
>   California","link":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72429666","source":"http://www.kuakes.com","north":40.293999,"west":122.000999,"lat":40.294167,"lng":-122.001335,"depth":10,"mag":2.2,"time":"2015-04-10
>   20:19:01 UTC","timestamp":1428697141}

and so on and so forth...

I would like to parse and populate the key/value pairs in a single dictionary object only for now.

Comment: You can't have a dictionary with multiple keys called id. Keys are unique. Do you want an array of dictionaries, where what you're calling the first and second entries would be instead, the first and second elements of an array?

Comment: First off, what you have there is an ARRAY.  It contains a bunch of JSON objects (dictionaries), the first of which gives response status and count and the rest of which appear to contain info on individual events.  If you want to reorganize the data as you describe, simply write the code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use something like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

Then create a class like this to store stuff in:

```
class Entry {
    var title, link, source, north, west, lat, lng, dept, mag, time, timestamp
}
```